# Acumatica : Switching Selector Attribute on the same DAC Field

Tags: acumatica

Good Day!

I have a field in my DAC where I need to change the Selector attribute depending on the setup that I set on my preferences. As you may know, there is an existing LeadSelector Attribute and CustomerSelector Attribute on acumatica. I wish to change the selector attribute of that given field if I set Customer on my preferences, and vice versa.

Is there any available resources right here now?

I've been thinking of creating an Extended Selector attribute on which I will check what is the preference setup then inherit the LeadSelector or CustomerSelector on the Extended Selector. But I think it might not be possible.

The other thing that I've been thinking, is to add both selectors on the attribute and remove them from the graph level whenever which preference is set up.

I'm also thinking of creating 2 selectors, on which I will hide the other depending on the preference setup. But the problem is, the selector is being used not only on one page, and it's a hassle if I create 2 selectors just to solve that issue. And also in the future it might not just lead and customer selectors.

I hope you can help me, I'm out of ideas. Thank you so much.

**UPDATE 09-24-2019**

I created a custom selector attribute for Lead and Customer Selector attributes. And it's working just I want it to be, but now my problem is, the description field won't show on the text box or on that field, also, there are error such as 'Investor name cannot be found in the system'.

**Investor Selector Attribute**

```
public class InvestorSelectorAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{

    public InvestorSelectorAttribute() : base(typeof(REInvestor.accountID))
    {
        DescriptionField = typeof(REInvestor.acctName);
        SubstituteKey = typeof(REInvestor.acctName);
    }

    protected IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        var leads = new PXSelect<Contact,
                        Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.lead>,
                        Or<Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>,
                            And<Contact.status, Equal<LeadStatusesAttribute.converted>>>>>>(this._Graph);

        var contacts = new PXSelect<BAccountR>(this._Graph);

        REFeature setup = PXSelect<REFeature>.Select(this._Graph);

        if (setup.InvestorType == InvestorTypesAttribute.LeadVal)
        {
            foreach (Contact lead in leads.Select())
            {
                yield return new REInvestor { AccountID = lead.ContactID, AcctName = lead.DisplayName };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (BAccountR contact in contacts.Select())
            {
                yield return new REInvestor { AccountID = contact.BAccountID, AcctName = contact.AcctName, AcctCD = contact.AcctCD };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Unbound REInvestor DAC**

```
[Serializable]
[PXCacheName("Investor")]
public class REInvestor : IBqlTable
{
    public abstract class accountID : BqlInt.Field<accountID> { }
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = REMessages.DisplayNames.AccountID, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual int? AccountID { get; set; }

    public abstract class acctName : BqlString.Field<acctName> { }
    [PXDBString(128, InputMask = "", IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = REMessages.DisplayNames.AccountName, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual string AcctName { get; set; }

    public abstract class acctCD : BqlString.Field<acctCD> { }
    [PXDBString(128, InputMask = "", IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = REMessages.DisplayNames.AcctCD, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual string AcctCD { get; set; }
}
```

** DAC Integration **

```
[PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = REMessages.DisplayNames.InvestorsName, Required = true)]
    [InvestorSelector()]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual int? ContactID { get; set; }
```

I really need your help and suggestions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ok to have 2 fields defined and one displayed.
Each one with his own selector, and PXUIField Description.
You set visibility for one of them base on the setup field at graph level (RowSelected event)

In case you need to merge them on persist (persist both fields in one bound field), you can simply use 2 unbound fields for collecting/displaying data.

- on updating/persisting event, you can update the values from unbound fields to unique database field
- on retrieve you can make an Data View - Delegate to populate the unbound fields base on configuration;

When you plan to move on multiple pages (graphs) you move the code from the graph to an PXEventSubscriberAttribute
You add the new attribute at the DAC level.
This way you have access on all Graph events that may need (persisting, selecting, updating, ...). All the code stays in one place.

For multiple DACs you still need to create the fields; add them the new attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.